# dynamic textbox in pressing enter key

Tags: javascript, html

can someone help me with my code? everytime I type in my textbox it create multiple textbox but I want to create a program that everytime I hit enter key it create another textbox.

here's my code:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function changeIt() {
     var i = 1;
     my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML +"<br><input type='text' name='mytext'+ i><br/>"
    }
</script>
<body>
    <form name="form" action="post" method="">
      <input type="text" name=t1 onkeydown="changeIt()">
      <div id="my_div"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vy2634o5/2/)

What you have done in your code was to create a textfield whenever a key press occurs..To create a textfield only when enter key is pressed you have to check the keycode of the pressed button.

So, Please change your JS a little bit as follows..

```
function changeIt(event) {
  var key = event.which || event.keyCode;
  if (key == '13') {
    var i = 1;
    my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML + "<br><input type='text' name='mytext'+ i><br/>"
  }
}
```

Please make sure that you replace your `<input>` also as follows

```
<input type="text" name=t1 onkeydown="changeIt(event)">
```

Please read more about keyCode in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode).. Also, if you want to find out the keyCode of any button, please check [keycode.info](http://keycode.info/)

Comment: thank you for your help, my program is now running well.

Comment: `e.which` and `e.keyCode` are both `number`, not `string`, so it would probably be better to compare them as `key === 13`. Anyway, both of them are also deprecated. `e.key` or `e.code` should be used instead, which also makes the code easier to understand. Just keep in mind some old browsers used some non-standard codes, so, for example, left is usually `'LeftArrow'` and right is `'RightArrow'`, but on IE it's just `'Left'` and `'Right'` instead. Also, take a look at https://keyjs.dev. I will add information about these kinds of cross-browser incompatibilities soon! 

Answer (score 0):

Your current JS function is being execute every time a button is pressed because you're use the event `onkeydown` which will capture **any** key pressing.

Do this:

```
<script>
var changed = function(e){
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == '13'){

        /* YOUR EXECUTION CODE */

    }
}
</script>

<form name="form" action="post" method="">
  <input type="text" name="t1">
  <div id="my_div"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: you can remove the`onkeydown="changeIt()"` in the input

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `<input>` everytime **any** key is pressed. Instead, you should check if <kbd>Enter</kbd> was pressed using `e.key` or `e.code` (note both `e.which` and `e.keyCode` are depreacted).

Also, consider using [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)  instead of `innerHTML`. Otherwise, every time you add a new `<input>`, all the existing ones will be re-created and lose their values.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const inputs = document.getElementById('inputs');

input.addEventListener('keydown', ({ key }) => {
  if (key !== 'Enter') return;
  
  const newInput = document.createElement('input');
  
  newInput.type = 'text';
  newInput.name = `mytext${ inputs.children.length }`;
  
  inputs.appendChild(newInput);
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form name="form" action="post" method="">
  <input type="text" id="input">
  <div id="inputs"></div>
</form>
```

If you need to check KeyboardEvent's properties values such as `e.key`, `e.code`, `e.which` or `e.keyCode`, you can use https://keyjs.dev:

[image: Key.js \ JavaScript KeyboardEvent's key codes & key identifiers]

**Disclaimer: I'm the author.**